# Using Hess's law to find molar enthalpy of formation without an initial reaction

Tags: thermodynamics, enthalpy

I'm having issues relating Hess's law to this question:

> The given chemical equation represent the combustion of ammonia and the combustion of hydrogen
>
> $$
> \begin{align}
> \ce{4 NH3 + 3 O2 &->6 H2O + 2N2} &\qquad &ΔH_1 = \pu{-1516 kJ} \tag{1} \\
> \ce{2 H2 + O2 &-> 2 H2O} &\qquad &ΔH_2 = \pu{-572 kJ} \tag{2} \\
> \end{align}
> $$
>
> What is the molar enthalpy of formation for ammonia?
>
> **A.** $\pu{-100 kJ}$; **B.** $\pu{-50 kJ}$; **C.** $\pu{50 kJ}$; **D.** $\pu{100 kJ}$.

I'm not sure how I would apply the  product–reactant equation here, or rearrange the equation to get my answer since I don't have an initial reaction to compare it to. How would I go about answering this question?

Comment: There is all the info you need. I suggest you start with writing an actual equation for the synthesis of ammonia and then use linear combination of the provided equations.

Comment: Hold on a sec, that's for 2 mols of $\ce{NH3}$, I think you forgot to divide it in half (it should be around -50 kJ/mol):)

Comment: Are you at least given the heart of combustion?

Comment: @user9988, be sure to update the question with your approach to a solution, to make this question less homework-y.

Answer (score 1):

Since you are asked to find the enthalpy of formation for ammonia, it's convenient to write the equation of ammonia synthesis normalized for $\pu{1 mol}$ of $\ce{NH3}$:

$$\ce{0.5 N2 + 1.5 H2 -> NH3}$$

To obtain this equation and apply Hess's law, the following linear combination of the provided equations should be used:

$$
\begin{align}
\ce{4 NH3 + 3 O2 &->6 H2O + 2N2} & ΔH_1 &= \pu{-1516 kJ} &&|\cdot(-0.25) \tag{1} \\
\ce{2 H2 + O2 &-> 2 H2O} & ΔH_2 &= \pu{-572 kJ} &&|\cdot 0.75 \tag{2} \\
\hline
\ce{0.5 N2 + 1.5 H2 &-> NH3} & ΔH_3 &= -0.25ΔH_1 + 0.75ΔH_2 \tag{3}
\end{align}
$$

So the final answer is

$$ΔH_3 = -0.25\cdot(\pu{-1516 kJ}) + 0.75\cdot(\pu{-572 kJ}) = \pu{-50 kJ}$$

The catch here is that you are asked to find *molar* enthalpy of formation, and calculating for the "convenient" equation with integer coefficients

$$\ce{N2 + 3 H2 -> 2 NH3}$$

you eventually would obtain the doubled value of $\pu{-100 kJ mol-1}$ referred to $\pu{2 mol}$ of ammonia (I almost fell for it, too).